# Save multiple images on the server

Tags: php, cakephp, jqplot

The following function renders a jqplot chart:

```
function renderChart($chart_id = null){
    //magic...
}
```

$chart_id defines the id of the chart to be rendered. Each chart has it's own settings.

In the corresponding view of the renderChart function (`../views/charts/render_chart.ctp`) the chart is displayed. I know that to save it I can use javascript and ajax.

What I need to do is save multiple charts as images on the server.

```
function saveMultipleImages(){
    renderChart(1);
    renderChart(2);
    renderChart(3);
}
```

But this solution just redirects me to the first function and stops there.

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you already have the renderChart function working or are you asking for help with that `magic`?

Answer (score 0):

```
function renderChart($chart_id = null){
    //magic...

   return true;
  }


function saveMultipleImages(){
 $this->renderChart(1);
 $this->renderChart(2);
 $this->renderChart(3);
}
```